# MySQL, ODBC driver Access collation problem

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a web aplication with an MySQL database (Collation Latin-1) and everything works fine, but when I connect to the MySQL database through Mysql connector ODBC in MS Access the data it´s not displayed correctly when everything works perfectly on web based system.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the displayed data along with what you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it UTF-8 and the problem will be solved